# Execute a third application in DOS with Int 21h/4Bh using MASM

Tags: assembly, x86-16, dos, masm, fasm

I do not understand, why the int21h/4Bh make this problems for MASM. I found a ASM code for FASM that seems to work. But with MASM it won't. The problem seems that in FASM INC files are in the standard embedded. I would like a  simple and compact code for MASM.

My Goal:
exec2 STARTAPP.COM/EXE Parameter1 Parameter2 ....

The START.COM/EXE start with:
STARTAPP Parameter1 Parameter2 ...

Working asm code in FASM:

````
org     100h

; first, we need to free the conventional memory we don't use,
; so there will be some memory available for the program we want
; to run, if we used MZ format of executable, the directive
; "heap 0" would be enough for this purpose, in case of .com
; program we have to free that memory manually be resizing the
; memory block starting at our PSP (es is already set to it)

        mov     ah,4Ah                  ; resize memory block
        mov     bx,10010h shr 4         ; only memory needed for .com
        int     21h

; now set up the pointer to command line in the parameters block

        mov     word [cmdline],_command
        mov     word [cmdline+2],ds

; we are ready to execute the program now

        mov     ax,4B00h                ; load and execute program
        mov     dx,_program             ; ASCIIZ path of program
        mov     bx,params               ; parameter block
        int     21h

        int     20h                     ; exit program


_program db 'c:\command.com',0
_command db 0                           ; length of command line
         db 13                          ; must end with CR character

params:
 environment dw 0       ; segment of environment, 0 means to use parent's one
 cmdline dd ?           ; pointer to command line
 default_fcb1 dd 0      ; pointers to file control blocks
 default_fcb2 dd 0      ```
````

I would like to convert this code to MASM with this:

```
; Assembling: masm exec2.asm

code    segment 
        assume cs:code,ds:code
        org   100h             
start:

; first, we need to free the conventional memory we don't use,
; so there will be some memory available for the program we want
; to run, if we used MZ format of executable, the directive
; "heap 0" would be enough for this purpose, in case of .com
; program we have to free that memory manually be resizing the
; memory block starting at our PSP (es is already set to it)

        mov     ah,4Ah                  ; resize memory block
        mov     bx,10010h shr 4         ; **< asm(14): error A2084: constant value too large**
        int     21h

; now set up the pointer to command line in the parameters block

        mov     word [cmdline], offset command ; **< .asm(19): error A2009: syntax error in expression**
        mov     word [cmdline+2],ds ; **< .asm(20): error A2009: syntax error in expression**

; we are ready to execute the program now

        mov     ax,4B00h                ; load and execute program
        mov     dx, offset program             ; ASCIIZ path of program
        mov     bx,params               ; parameter block
        int     21h

        int     20h                     ; exit program


program db 'c:\command.com', 0
command db 0                           ; length of command line
         db 13                          ; must end with CR character

params:
 environment dw 0       ; segment of environment, 0 means to use parent's one
 cmdline dd ?           ; pointer to command line
 default_fcb1 dd 0      ; pointers to file control blocks
 default_fcb2 dd 0      

code    ends
end  start

END
```

Comment: The 4Ah service call can use bx = 1000h (or 10000h shr 4). `mov bx, params` should probably be `mov bx, offset params`. `mov word [...]` needs to use `word ptr` for the size keyword.

Comment: I'm curious about one thing. What version of MASM are you using?

Comment: @MichaelPetch I use MASM 6.11

Comment: Oh I realize what is going on. I was right with my original comments (now deleted). MASM 5.1 had a bug/feature where it would give you an error trying to do `10000h shr 4`. That was resolved in MASM6+ but only if you invoked MASM using `ML.EXE` rather than `MASM.EXE`. I see from a code comment you assemble with `MASM.EXE` in MASM6.11. So you'd get an error if you do `MASM EXEC2.ASM` as MASM is a wrapper around `ML.EXE` that defaults to MASM5.1 compatibility (it passes `/Zm` to `ML.EXE`). If you invoke ML directly with `ML.EXE /AT EXEC2.ASM` that constant too large will disappear.

Comment: If you use `ML.EXE /Zm /AT EXEC2.ASM` with the `/Zm` MASM510 option  it will give the error again. Note: `/AT` forces ML.EXE to generate a .COM program rather than .EXE. You might consider just invoking ML.EXE directly rather than using MASM.EXE.

Comment: And as @ecm said you need to change lines like `mov word [...]` to `mov word ptr [...]`. Unlike FASM (and NASM) MASM requires the `ptr` directive after `word`, `byte` etc on memory operands.

Comment: @ecm - Yes means mov word ptr [...]

I fixed the code.

I do not know, but I can not start third programs with `exec.com myprogram.com` 
I tested `exec.com /c myprogeam.com` too. But with no result.
Anybody know why?

Comment: What happens instead? I do not see how the FASM code could work but the MASM code not.

Comment: @ecm - Sorry my mistake. This is an code snip only. I tested it onetime on a wrong COM file. The same with FASM > [link](https://board.flatassembler.net/topic.php?t=290)

Comment: You didn't reply to my question. What happens instead? What do you mean by "no result"?

Comment: @ecm - The compile application start and ends. Nothing.
When I use parameters `exec.com /c myprogramm.com` or `exec.com myprogramm.com` it happens nothing. Exec start and ends with no error or crash.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't in a new shell process? Your system call passes the executable name `c:\command.com` and an empty command line tail. (It doesn't matter what you pass to `exec.com` because it never reads its command line.) If you enter an `exit` command does it behave as usual or do you exit only the inner shell? If even that doesn't work try running your program in a debugger, eg https://pushbx.org/ecm/web/#projects-ldebug (If you trace the 21.4B00 call and it pops up a DOS shell then it worked, otherwise tell us what Carry Flag and what `ax` value you get.)

Comment: Does the FASM program behave any differently than your MASM program?

Comment: @ecm No, in FASM is the same problem then MASM.

Comment: Refer to my second to last comment on debugging then. Also, you should probably edit your question to remove the lines "I found a ASM code for FASM that seems to work" and "Working asm code in FASM" as it doesn't do what you want it to.

Comment: Also, a working example is available in https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/callver/file/05f94780ecb4/callver.asm for NASM. It invokes a shell from the `%COMSPEC%` variable with `/C program.exe parameters...`

Comment: @ecm - I check my code and the problem is only, that the code lose the parameters
ex. `/C program.exe parameters...`
The COMSPEC will start normal.

Comment: This is intended. You will have to change the code if you want it to use the command line tail that you pass to it. You need to set the low word of `cmdline` to 128, and the high word (as is) to `ds`.